# SQL if statement

Tags: sql

I want to be able to write:

```
IF PROV_ID = PROVIDER NOT ON FILE or blank then use BILLING_PROV 
ELSE USE PROV_ID
```

`Billing_prov` is a column name, so I want to return that value.

Comment: Not even close to enough information. What have you tried? What is your table structure? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT
 CASE WHEN (PROV_ID = [PROVIDER NOT ON FILE or blank])
      THEN BILLING_PROV 
      ELSE PROV_ID
      END
FROM
 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm making an assumption that "not on file or blank" means null

```
SELECT COALESCE(PROV_ID, BILLING_PROV) as Whatever
FROM ...
```

Comment: +1 for the assumption. I would guess he also wants to check if it's `=''`